# using a chroot jail to change the results of uname -n

Tags: rhel, chroot

I just learned what a chroot jail is so excuse me if this questions doesn't make much sense.

Basically I have two processes running locally in my machine and would like the results of "uname -n" to be different for each of these processes (and all their children).  How can I use a chroot jail to do this for me?

Comment: In resent times there have been new features added to Unix name-spaces, cgroups, etc. These are much more powerful, than chroot. I think that the chroot system call is now implemented using them. So it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with chroot. But you can do it by changing [UTS namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/namespaces.7.en.html#UTS_namespaces_(CLONE_NEWUTS)), for example using [unshare](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/unshare.1.en.html).

```
mysystem# unshare --uts sh -c 'hostname test; uname -n'; uname -n
test
mysystem
```

The same, interactively:

First terminal:

```
mysystem# unshare --uts bash
mysystem# hostname test
mysystem# exec bash # to refresh prompt
test# uname -n
test
test# strace uname -n 2>&1|tail
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5592a93f6000
brk(0x5592a9417000)                     = 0x5592a9417000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="test", ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(1, "test\n", 5test
)                   = 5
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
test#
```

Second terminal, unaffected:

```
mysystem# uname -n
mysystem
mysystem#
```

Simply exiting the shell on the first terminal, returns to the calling one which never changed namespace:

```
test# exit
mysystem#
```

Note that *only* the hostname changes. There are similar [namespaces](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/namespaces.7.en.html) for various features (network, mount points...). That's the founding brick of containers: all of them are then in use (the other main brick for containers is [cgroups](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/cgroups.7.en.html)).

Comment: will this apply to all the processes that are run from that terminal?

Comment: So if I try running a C program that calls uname from sys/utsname this should return a different name right?

Comment: This resolved my problem! Is there a way to allow a non-root to change the namespace?  What are the security concerns in allowing someone access to the unshare command?